# Validate form in React js

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, forms, validation

I'm trying to validate form *onSubmit* in my React Application.

This is one of the components which is rendered in main file. This components is called by click on **set alarm** button. This is not that important ,but what is ,I'm sending **getInfo()** function from main component to this component as a prop. I need to call this function when validation returns **true**

Form consists of 3 input fields and one button ,but I don't need to check the first one.

Since my application is Alarm clock ,and this form pops up when you click **Set alarm** button , I need to check if

- First input is not empty and if it's value is not over 24 (in this input you set hours for alarm)
- Second input is not empty and if it's value is not over 60 (in this input you set minutes for alarm)

My idea was to create **States** for these values and create functions which are supposed to update states. Functions are called **onChange** that specific input.

```
const [validate,setValidate] = useState({
    message:'',
    hours:'',
    minutes:''
}) 

function updateHours(e){
    let value = e.target.value
    setValidate(prevState => ({
        ...prevState,
       hours:value
    }))
}

function updateMinutes(e){
    let value = e.target.value;
    setValidate(prevState => ({
        ...prevState,
        minutes:value
    }))
}
```

To this point everything works fine. Then I've tried to create new function which will be validating these values and should return the result. This function will be called **onSubmit** ,and if returns true ,it means everything is okay and form will be send.

```
let getInfo = props.getInfo;

function validateForm(){
    if(validate.hours > 24){
        alert('enter correct hours !')
        return false;
    }

    if(validate.minutes > 60){
        alert('enter correct minutes !')
        return false;
    }

    return getInfo;
}
```

I've tried to Google it how to do this onSubmit and all I can find was this approach ,which did not work. It behaves like no function is called.

```
<form onSubmit="return validateForm">
     <FontAwesomeIcon 
        icon={faTimesCircle} 
        className="closeIcon"
        onClick={() => setAlarm(false)} />

     <h3>Please set your alarm</h3>

     <label htmlFor="text">Message</label>
     <input type="text" id="text" autoComplete="off" autoFocus="on" />

     <div className="flex">
       <div className="inputNumber">
          <label htmlFor="hours">Hour</label>
          <input type="number" id="hours" name="hours" onChange={updateHours} />
       </div>
                                
       <div className="inputNumber">
          <label htmlFor="minutes">Minute</label>
          <input type="number" id="minutes" name="minutes" onChange={updateMinutes} />
       </div>
    </div>
    <button onClick={()=>setAlarm(false)}>SET ALARM</button>
</form>
```

Has anyone encountered this kind of problem or can you give me advice what to do with it? Also I'm open-minded to some better approach for this. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

First of all I should say that it is not neessary to make validation in web platform by yourself since the browser validated everything itself. See [Constraint Validation API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Constraint_validation). And I know that feels strange since most of the developers do it themselves. I do not see any necessity though.

What you have to do is **constraint** the values, but not validate, with various attributes accoring to your needs; type, pattern, min, max, minlength, maxlength, required etc.

You will be equipped by some properties (`validity` etc.), methods (`checkValidity` etc.), attributes (`type`, `pattern`, `min`, `max` etc.), pseudo classes (`:invalid`, `:valid` etc.), and events (`invalid` etc.) that you will need if the user input is valid with respect to your constraints.

Using these you will have the reason why, and when it is invalid, and opportunities to set a custom invalid state message or style. By the way It does not matter if you use a framework like React or anything else, it is still there to use.

Comment: Thank you for answer. But I wanted to do something like if number for hours is above 24 ,you are unable to send that form and red border about that specific input will show. I have added attributes such as min="1" max ="24" but it works only if you click those numbers ,not add by keyboard. Second thing about it. When I hit enter form will be not send(no alarm is added to state array) but it disappears ,error sentence will pop up,but only for like 1-2 seconds.

Comment: @Pinnci I did not get what you mean by "it works only if you click those numbers ,not add by keyboard". 
`min` `max` is for input types; `number`, `range`, and *date and time related* types. Just to remind you to use one of them with those.
Also there is a type `time` input, but support varies and you do  not have to use it. The way you do with two inputs is preferrable support-wise.
I also waat clarification in second point too. Does page reload when you hit enter? If so you need to call `event.preventDefault()` in the `onSubmit` handler.

Comment: Sorry ,by that sentence i mean - when you hover mouse on input type number , smal arrows will show up inside that input . Arrow up and arrow down. If you click arrow up,number inside that input will increase by one and If you click arrow down ,number will decrease. That is what I meant by ‘click numbers’. In this case min and max attributes work fine and you are not able to ‘click’ number higher that number which is in max attribute. Second case ,which i’ve described ‘by keyboard’ - when you click inside that input a simply just type for example 789,it will let you type it and when you hit

Comment: send,only then it will notify you about wrong number value. I was looking for something like when you type in hours input for example number 46, just after you type 6,that input will get style of border red,and red error message will pop up right under that input . I’ve solved this yesterday and everything works as i want to . :) but thanks for your answer and your time :)

Comment: You are welcome. Still you can use the API I have told you and avoid leaking validaiton logic and repeating what browser does for you. In such cases you need to register an event handler for `blur` or `input` on input elements that calls `event.target.checkValidity()` among other things. Example: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Constraint_validation#Examples